# Why is npx not working even after running npm cache clean and updating npm version?

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

[when i writ npx create react app dont work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTr1T.png)

I ran npm cache clean --force
npm i -g npm@8.5.1
npm config set fetch-retry-mintimeout 20000

npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 120000
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
create react app in different drive (D or C)

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the error text instead of adding a screenshot?